# Prove that $S$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S=\{ (x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2 :xy<1 \}$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $S$ is an open set.

I have tried to construct an open ball $B((x,y),r)$ but the value of $r$ I cannot determine.

Comment: $f(x,y) = xy$ is continuous...

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Let $(x_0,y_0)\in S$ and let $d:=1-x_0y_0>0$.

Let $r>0$ and let $(x,y)\in B((x_0,y_0),r)$. Then, by triangular inequality, $|x-x_0|<r$ and $|y-y_0|<r$. Therefore
$$xy=(x-x_0)(y-y_0)+x_0(y-y_0)+y_0(x-x_0)+x_0y_0\leq r^2+|x_0|r+|y_0|r+1-d\stackrel{?}{<} 1$$
Now are you able to find a value for $r$ such that the last inequality holds?

Moreover use  LutzL's hint: assume that $r<1$. 
So it suffices to find $0<r<1$ such that
$$r+|x_0|r+|y_0|r\stackrel{?}{<} d.$$

Comment: You can also demand from the start that $r<1$ so that the last inequality can be made linear in $r$.

Comment: Yes, so this is hint number two.

Comment: I have understood the first hint. Thank you so much sir. This result somehow fits perfectly